# Style text of selected element in QComboBox or QListWidget?

Tags: c++, qt, stylesheet, qlistwidget

Is it possible, using stylesheets, to change the appearence of the text contained in a selected item such as a QComboBox or a QListWidget? 
I've tried with a QListWidget but I can change everything except for the text properties.

This sample changes the text color but not its font:

```
QListWidget m_pListMain = new QListWidget(this);
m_pListMain->setStyleSheet("QListWidget:item:selected{"
                               "color: red;"
                               "font: bold;"
                               "}");
```

This, instead, works correctly:

```
QListWidget m_pListMain = new QListWidget(this);
m_pListMain->setStyleSheet("QListWidget{"
                               "color: red;"
                               "font: bold;"
                               "}");
```

But obviously it changes all the items, not just the selected one.
What am I missing? (I am assuming the problem is the same with the QComboBox).

Comment: did you try `QListWidget:item:selected:active ?`

Comment: Tried thanks, but that still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I found is by connecting to this SIGNAL http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qlistwidget.html#currentItemChanged
:

```
currentItemChanged(QListWidgetItem*,QListWidgetItem*)
```

then, in a SLOT, switch the font at runtime:

```
_HandleListItemChanged(QListWidgetItem *p_pItemCurrent, QListWidgetItem *p_pItemPrevious)
{
// Switch fonts: only selected must be bold
    QFont l_Font = p_pItemCurrent->font();
    l_Font.setBold(true);
    p_pItemCurrent->setFont(l_Font);

    l_Font = p_pItemPrevious->font();
    l_Font.setBold(false);
    p_pItemPrevious->setFont(l_Font);
}
```